# DataGridView only 1 show 1 row

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I have a DatagridView with a datasource but my datagridview only draws 1 row.

My code is something along these lines:

**Declaration of List**

```
List<Texture> LoadedTextures = new List<Texture>();
```

**Custum Datasource Object**

```
public class Texture
{
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Adding Method**

```
private void LoadImage(string FileName)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FileName);

    if (LoadedTextures.Count > 0 && 
       LoadedTextures.Where(x => x.Name == file.Name).Count() > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Already a texture with that name", "error",
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(CurrLevel.TileWidth, CurrLevel.TileHeight);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        gr.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(FileName), 
           new Rectangle(0, 0, CurrLevel.TileWidth, CurrLevel.TileWidth));
    }
    var text = new Texture
    {
        Image = (Image)newImage,
        Name = file.Name
    };
    LoadedTextures.Add(text);
    if(Tiles.DataSource == null)Tiles.DataSource = LoadedTextures;  
}
```

When debugging I also noticed that my Datasource contains the loaded elements but the datagridview only draws 1 row though.

P.S : I tried , DataGridView.Refresh() , DataGridView.RefreshEdit() , Assigning the Datasource everytime when a change is made but none of these helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a bindinglist worked for me (used the change event to refresh the list) ,
Tnx for all the reponses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a web app, I tried the following to confirm one of my suspicions:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                myList.Add(i);
        }
    }

    protected void btn_AddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myList.Add(10);
        Console.Write(myList.Count()); //always prints "1"
    }
```

The list loses all of its items which is what I'm guessing is happening to you. As for how to fix it, I'm not positive but at the very least it narrowed down the source of your problem.

If it's not a web app, then I'm sorry as I'm not familiar with the lifespan of the other types of applications.

Comment: My application is an Windows Form Application,I also added a button to check count and when adding a new item my count increases but its still displaying 1 row

Answer (score 0):

I think your check for if the DataSource is null is probably the issue:

```
if(Tiles.DataSource == null) Tiles.DataSource = LoadedTextures;
```

Just remove the check and assign it directly, since the first time you add one `Texture`, it will change it to non null, then after that it will never update the DataSource again, no matter how many more you add:

```
Tiles.DataSource = LoadedTextures
```

If your loading multiple `Textures`, it might be better to load them all then call `Tiles.DataSource = LoadedTextures` once, instead of every time you load a new `Texture`

Comment: Hmm, Now I don't get any rows.

Comment: Hmm using a bindinglist worked for me (used the change event to refresh the list) , Can't answer my own question though ^^

Comment: @Svexo - Sure you can, if you found the solution, you can add it as an answer and accept it.